# Managing a log stream in C++ in a cout-like notation

Tags: c++, logging, printing, operator-overloading

I have a class in c++ in order to write log files for an application of mine. I have already built the class and it works, it is something like this:

```
class Logger {
   std::string _filename;
public: 
   void print(std::string tobeprinted);
}
```

Well, it is intuitive that, in order to print a line in the log file, for an object of Logger, it is simply necessary to do the following:

```
Logger mylogger("myfile.log");
mylogger.print(std::string("This is a log line"));
```

Well. Using a method approach is not the same as using a much better pattern like << is.
I would like to do the following:

```
Logger mylogger("myfile.log");
mylogger << "This is a log line";
```

That's all. I suppose I must overload the << operator... But overloading using this signature (the classic one):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const MyObj& o);
```

But I do not have a ostream...
So, should I do as follows?

```
Logger& operator<<(Logger& output, const std::string& o);
```

Is this the right way?
Thanks

Comment: What functionality do you want to provide that isn't in `std::ofstream`?

Comment: I already have all functionalities in my log class, here I just needed a way to make things more c++ like using << operator.

Comment: And what functionalities are you providing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the right way. But you'll have to add << operator overloads for every data type that you need to log.

Comment: Ah one more question sory, If I would use char* can I do the following: Logger& operator<<(Logger& output, const char* o)?

Comment: If your underlying implementation uses a standard io stream, then you don't need to overload for each type, simply template the `operator<<` and it will work fine.

Comment: ...which makes it the wrong way. What he wants to do is create a new stream destination, not an entirely new way of streaming.

Answer (score 6):

```
class Log
{
public:

    enum Level { Debug, Error, Info };

    static ostream& GetStream() { return cout; }
    static bool IsLevelActive(Level l) { return true; }
};

#ifndef NO_LOG
#define LOG_ERROR(M)   do { if (Log::IsLevelActive(Log::Error))   (Log::GetStream() << "ERR: " << M << "\n"); } while (false)
#define LOG_INFO(M)    do { if (Log::IsLevelActive(Log::Info))    (Log::GetStream() << "INF: " << M << "\n"); } while (false)
#define LOG_WARNING(M) do { if (Log::IsLevelActive(Log::Warning)) (Log::GetStream() << "WRN: " << M << "\n"); } while (false)
#else
#define LOG_ERROR(M)
#define LOG_INFO(M)
#define LOG_WARNING(M)
#endif

struct MyObject {
    int a, b;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const MyObject& obj) {
    ostr << "(a=" << obj.a << ", b=" << obj.b << ")";
    return ostr;
}

void test() {
    int v1 = 42;
    int v2 = 43;
    LOG_INFO("value1=" << v1 << ", value2=" << v2);

    MyObject o = {1, 2};
    LOG_INFO("obj=" << o);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply make `Logger` a sub-class of either std::ostream or std::ostringstream?  Then all that functionality will already be implemented.

Comment: Yes, it is a correct way... I suppose, in my case, I would suffer from an overdimensioning issue... I mean, yes i would have all functionalities but many of them would be useless for me... I just need some sort of wrapper, Only one method is my interest, nothing more....

Comment: Neither `ostream` nor `ostringstream` have many virtual functions so it's not clear to me exactly how you would extend or enhance functionality that isn't already in `ostream` or `ostringstream`.

Comment: @Charles: My personal suggestion would be to compose on it, rather than inherit, but that could work too.

Comment: One should not subclass `std::ostream`. If you want to change the target of a stream subclass `std::basic_streambuf`, and if you want to add output functions overload `operator<<`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Exactly, and to know which (or whether both) is appropriate we need to know what extra functionality over a `std::ofstream` the `Logger` class is trying to provide.

Comment: @Charles:  I was thinking with ostringstream that one would add functions that use the string data.  I am not sure, but can't help thinking that there has to be a useful way of using that existing functionality rather than replicating it. @Billy ONeal's suggestion of basing on the abstract std::basic_streambuf is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to create whole new streams, as you then need to redefine all the stream operators. You'd only do that if you want to change entirely how data gets converted into character data. (Ick).

What I've found best for this is to create a class that will keep track of a stream and send its contents to a destination of my choice (the logger) when destructed. That, combined with a smattering of macros, gives you what you are looking for: stream syntax for logging.

Boost actually has some classes that help with this. Look at [iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html).